# How to add foreign keys with IF EXISTS/IF NOT EXISTS statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, foreign-keys, sql-insert

Im trying to insert a foreign key into multiple tables by checking if the key exists already, if not it should insert it.
But when I try to run my script it just skips the whole insert part, even when all the individual commands work properly.
(i use MS SQL Server 2008)

```
begin transaction;

declare @isid as nvarchar(50);
declare @fk as nvarchar(50);
declare @statement as VARCHAR(2000);

declare @db_cursor CURSOR;
set @db_cursor = cursor FOR SELECT Name FROM [sys.Component] order by Name;

open @db_cursor;
fetch next from @db_cursor into @isid;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    SELECT @fk = CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_' + @isid + '_Firma';
    if not exists (select @fk) 
        begin
        print 'NULL: ' + @fk;
        select @statement = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @isid + ' add constraint FK_' + 
           @isid + '_Firma FOREIGN KEY(FirmaCode) REFERENCES Firma(FirmaCode)';
        exec(@statement);
    end
    print 'NOT NULL: ' + @fk;
    fetch next from @db_cursor into @isid;
end
close @db_cursor;

commit transaction;
```

basic output i get is '`NOT NULL: FK_<TableName>_Firma`'

Thank you for any help you can provide with my problem.

Comment: Ultimately you are trying to add FK's to all your database tables(i am assuming each has FirmaCode column according to your above code) when not exist. Am i right?

Comment: @knkarthick24 Not all tables have the FirmaCode Column but the ones that do are inside sys.Component, so basically the tables on which I do the insert statement all have the FirmaCode column. And some of them already have the foreign key, so to avoid errors I first check which column doesn't have a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
begin transaction;

declare @isid as nvarchar(500);
declare @fk as nvarchar(500);
declare @statement as VARCHAR(2000);

declare @db_cursor CURSOR;
set @db_cursor = cursor FOR SELECT Name FROM [sys.Component] order by Name;

open @db_cursor;
fetch next from @db_cursor into @isid;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
select @fk = null
    SELECT @fk = CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_' + @isid + '_Firma';
    if (@fk is null) 
        begin
        print 'NULL: ' + @fk;
        select @statement = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @isid + ' add constraint FK_' + 
           @isid + '_Firma FOREIGN KEY(FirmaCode) REFERENCES Firma(FirmaCode)';
        exec(@statement);
    end
    print 'NOT NULL: ' + @fk;
    fetch next from @db_cursor into @isid;
end
close @db_cursor;

commit transaction;
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, though the output looks the same but slightly different http://i.gyazo.com/368039147fe3d0d567e35498d88adcb3.png
even in your code, it should run this statement "print 'NULL: ' + @fk;"
which i cannot see in the output

Comment: try Print 'NULL: '+ 'FK_' + @isid + '_Firma' instead of "print 'NULL: ' + @fk;"

Comment: this answer gave me the result I needed but not the expected output, non the less this answer worked for me, thank you so much SaravanaC

Comment: yes, Print 'NULL: '+ 'FK_' + @isid + '_Firma' seems to give me the expected output, now I know for sure the table got altered, thanks SaravanaC